# notifyDataSetChanged not working for me

Tags: android, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm new to Android eclipse so i need some help. I'm trying to make my ListView refresh after deleting all items from it, here's the code:

```
public void OnClickButtonSletWorkoutLog(View view)
{
    WorkoutLog workoutLog = new WorkoutLog();
    try
    {
        workoutLog.GemLog(this.getApplicationContext());
        ListView workoutLogListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ((BaseAdapter) workoutLogListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged -- Must be called from the main thread.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate it a little? maybe show an example? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a new `WorkoutLog` instance, but you're not really updating the adapter itself.

You're probably missing something like `adapter.setWorkoutLog(workoutLog)` (or whatever your actual method is called) before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have code where you are deleting the data right?

Call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() right after you are done with deleting all items from your data structure.

I wrote a [blog](http://blog.tech-armada.net/correct-implementation-of-baseadapter-notifydatasetchanged-in-android/) on this, see it to get an idea of how to do it correctly.